# Compiling Numerical Integration Data into a LaTeX Table

Tags: python, latex, numerical-methods

So I have a single integral of one variable and I am hoping to collate the data into a LaTeX table but I keep getting the error: 'int': object is not iterable.

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz


tvals = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]  # fixed values of t
xvals = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]  # fixed values of x


xi = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)  # xi is the integral variable!


def H(xi, x, t):
    series = np.zeros(xi.shape)
    for n in range(-300, 300):
        series += np.exp(-(x - 2 * n - xi) ** 2 / 4 * t) / np.sqrt(np.pi * t) - np.exp(-(x - 2 * n + xi)**2 / 4 * t)/ np.sqrt(np.pi * t)
    return series * 0.5 * np.sin(np.pi * xi)



for t in tvals:
    for x in xvals:
        TrapzH = trapz(H(xi, x, t), x=None, dx=0.1, axis=-1)
        print(TrapzH)




''' We are going to get a lot of values from this given the size of the lists of t and x values. So let us collate the 
data into a table and compile the table in LaTeX. '''

from tabulate import tabulate as tbl



for t in tvals:
    for x in xvals:
        TrapzH = trapz(H(xi, x, t), x=None, dx=0.1, axis=-1)
        headers = ["t Values", "x Values", "Output"]
        table = [t, x, TrapzH]
        print(tbl(table, headers, tablefmt="latex"))
```

Edit: I have now posted the exact error.
Error Code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 129, in <module>
    print(tbl(table, headers, tablefmt="latex"))
  File "", line 1427, in tabulate
    tabular_data, headers, showindex=showindex
  File "", line 1103, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = list(map(list, rows))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: It would be helpful to get to know the full error code and the line it occurs.

Comment: Added that now, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed speech marks around the entries for table. Whoops.